# Cannot connect in SSMS with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]

I found and added the server name through `<Browse for more...> -> Network Servers` so it exists and is correct.

What seems weird is that the `Password` field is empty and I cannot modify it...?
And when I try to Connect, I get this:

[image]

I am complete noob in DB management, so guide me thoroughly, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when the *default* database for some of the database user is dropped. From:

[Fix : Error: 4064 – Cannot open user default database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/) by [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/author/pinaldave/)

1. Click on the Option>> Button of the "Connect to Server" prompt.
2. Change the "connect to database" option to any existing database like master or msdb.
3. Click connect and it will successfully log you in.

Once you login, run following statement to change the default database:

```
ALTER LOGIN [your_login_name] 
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [your_choice];
```

Answer (score 1):

In windows authentication, you don't have to type the password, it will validate by AD.

The reason for Login error could be your login does not have access to the database server.

Please ask the database administrator to grant access to your login.